# One word adjective which means "that can't be given up"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

For Example:

People have (immense) faith in God. In place of immense, what would be the proper word to convey that 'the faith is not immense, but it is that which can't be given up, due to the fear of being alone. Even having less faith in God, we can't give up' ?

Comment: It's rare, but it exists: _unrelinquishable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [indispensable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indispensable) may convey the idea of something deemed as extremely important:

> - Absolutely necessary; essential. (AHD)

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

***inalienable*** [formal, mainly in law]

> inalienable
>
> adjective
>
> :  **incapable of being** alienated, **surrendered**, or transferred
>
> *inalienable human rights*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary